# Having a strange trouble with touchesMoved, position doesn't match location where screen is touched

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Am trying to make a game, where I drag gems around.

The hierarchy is:

**GameScene** (this is the view controller)

**gemBase**, which holds the gems (light grey) *SKSpriteNode*

**gems** *SKSpriteNode*

The gems are children of gemBase, which is a child of GameScene.

When the gemBase is at 0,0 everything works fine when I drag the gems. They are in the same place I am touching the screen. But I want to offer a left-handed feature, where I offset the gemBase to the rightsize of the screen. All gems automatically move with the base so I don't need to recalculate their positions.

But then, when I try to move the gems, they are offset to the right of where I am touching the screen. They are offset by as much as I move the gemBase.

Below is my only code where I handle touchesMoved (in GameScene)

Do I have to convert the touch.location?

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    super.touchesMoved(touches , with:event)
    guard touches.first != nil else { return }
    if toggleHigh {highliteGem(theGem: myGems[0], clearAll: true)}
    if let touch = touches.first, let node = myGV.currentGem, node.isMoving == true {
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        node.moved    = true
        node.position = touchLocation
        node.isMoving = true
        node.inSlot = false
        //addTrailToTwinkle(theNode: node)
    }
}
```

[image: Left vs. Right]

Comment: Where are you moving/offsetting gemBase to cater for left handed? Is that happening in didMove or somewhere else?

Comment: All done in GameScene's didMove. I create gemBase, create and position its gems. Then I check to see if we're playing left handed or right handed. If right, then I change gemBase.position (CGPoint).  By default it's created in the right handed position CGPoint (x:0, y:0).

Comment: I tried recreating your issue, what seemed to work was changing `let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)` to `let touchLocation = touch.location(in: gemBase)`

Comment: @JohnL First off, yes and thank you. I'd like to know why this seemed so obscure though. Did I miss something in the dox? I would think this would come up quite often with multiple parents and children SKNodes.

Comment: It will be down to coordinate systems. A child nodes position is based on its parents coordinate system, whereas the touch location would be based on the scenes coordinate system if using self. So some sort of conversion would need to happen or the use of the touch location of the gems parent instead. When i recreated your issue the gem moved variably rather than a fixed amount, which indicated a different coordinate system was being used.

Comment: @JohnL Would it be wrong then to have each SKSpriteNode handle its own touches?

Comment: The alternative approach is not to use the touch location to position the gem sprite, but instead you could use `touch.previousLocation` and `touch.Location`, then calculate the x difference and y difference between the two. This distance measurement could then be added to the x and y position of your gem sprite, so that it moves the same distance of that of your finger. This difference measurement could be applied to any sprite irrespective of parent.